# How to run the streamlit on python (jupyter)

Tags: streamlit

I am pretty new using streamlit. I am trying to run it on jupyter and I get the warning telling me to run the streamlit command on the browser. I was expecting an url adress, however I got a different option. If i run streamlit run <filename.py>, nothing happens. Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As your title hints at, Python and Jupyter are vastly different things. The easiest way is to use streamlit is like the text in pink says, run it on the command like of system where you've installed Streamlit.
Jupyter is an IDE with its own dashboarding ability, [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila). Note that more recently, there is [Solara](https://github.com/widgetti/solara), see [Web Apps in Python with Solara — A Streamlit Killer?](https://itnext.io/webapps-in-python-with-solara-a-streamlit-killer-ab6fcc7bf5d7), that builds on ipywidgets, see [here](https://twitter.com/maartenbreddels/status/1663079655425835009) and [here](https://twitter.com/giswqs/status/1662567330990137348) for more about that and how it makes things easier.

Streamlit and Jupyter can be used together but not as easily as you naively are attempting. You'll see [here](https://github.com/chekos/testing-streamlit-mybinder) you can use a proxy to get it to working alongside, but basically the streamlit app is a separate URL and software.
Or see [here](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/new-library-streamlit-jupyter-a-new-way-to-develop-streamlit-apps-in-jupyter-notebooks/35679). Note at the bottom, very pertinent to your title, it states:

> "I recently wanted to create a streamlit app at work, and found that it did not quite fit in with my preferred workflow with Jupyter - so this library was created to solve that problem"

That effort uses a trick to not actually run streamlit though, according to [the announcement post](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/new-library-streamlit-jupyter-a-new-way-to-develop-streamlit-apps-in-jupyter-notebooks/35679), "if the script is run from a jupyter notebook, then it wraps existing streamlit methods to replace them with ipywidgets alternatives".

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I have tried few options. I run the streamlit with cmd. If I run streamlit hello it opens the app, so it works. However, if i run my file, i get:"ImportError: cannot import name '_device' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import)". The other option,Voila,shows me all the outputs I run in the script, but it doesn't show the ones from the streamlit. And the last option,using streamlit and jupyter together,works partially; it plots the dataframe I am using for the streamlit, but it does not shows the charts I created.

Comment: I believe the best option is the first one, running it on the command, however I cannot figure out where that error is coming from...

Comment: Probably doesn't matter because you are not liking that option....I'm not quite following what you mean by "but it doesn't show the ones from the streamlit" in your comment "The other option,Voila,shows me all the outputs I run in the script, but it doesn't show the ones from the streamlit"? You'd have to add widgets to a notebook file that recapitulate the streamlit stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your message and sorry for the late replay. I have been off for a week. I do like all the options, I am trying to learn about all of them. At the moment I am trying to get the app open through the terminal and when the app opens in the browser it shows this error: "RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ScriptRunner.scriptThread'". I think it might have to do with asyncio, but not sure. Any recommendation? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you are thinking it has to do with asyncio because of [this thread](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/744#issuecomment-1496776244)? If running the demo fails, it is usually a problem with installation. It is odd though that you are using Anaconda which should help thing work. You may want to develop with Streamlit elsewhere if you are having problems. You'd deploy it elsewhere anyway.

Comment: Yes, I am using anaconda. Actually the demo works. The app works if I run streamlit hello, but it gives the error I mentioned before if I run streamlit run "C:\Users......py". Weird. I will try to do it elsewhere then.

Comment: If the 'hello' demo works then going elsewhere isn't going to help, I don't think. If you get an app in your browser with the demo then all is good. You need to run streamlit that way with your code. So if it isn't working, then modify the demo in steps adding your code and trying until it breaks. Otherwise your post and comments aren't clear on your problem at this point. Your original post was never going to work. You should start a new post with just your problem now as your original issue has been addressed if indeed the demo works on your system to make an app/dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood what I was doing wrong. I was trying to run the recommended on jupyter as "streamlit run C:\User.....(and the rest of the warning)". But now I understand that Anaconda won't run that recommendation from jupyter on that way. I needed to create a python script (not a jupyter notebook) and with Anaconda terminal navigate to that directory and run the streamlit with the name of the app.

The following link explains everything step by step with examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/76567170/8508004

Comment: Yes, this is why I was suggesting you take the working demo and convert it to use your code. But sometimes when new to something with a lot of moving parts it can be confusing. Glad you got it all together now. I think you mean to link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/76567170/8508004 and not where you have right now? You can imagine if another 20 people come along and add strange answers over to that post, the one you actually used won't be readily discernible unless you use the 'share' button and directly link to the answer.

Comment: Yes, it was a bit confusing for me, but thank you. I am also glad that I got to know Voila and Solara