# Few errors when trying to run streamlit in Anaconda terminal

Tags: streamlit

I have created a script on jupyter for a streamlit application. Once I run it, I got the indications:

```
Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
  command:

    streamlit run C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py [ARGUMENTS]
```

I run it as it says on the Anaconda terminal and the browser opens with an error. When I checked back the terminal, after the corresponding Local URL and Network URL address, it shows few more errors:

```
To connect another client to this kernel, use:
    --existing kernel-10020.json
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Unable to initialize signal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 674, in initialize
    self.init_signal()
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 520, in init_signal
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\signal.py", line 56, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
2022-02-29 15:34:13.094 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 991, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 113, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 680, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 524, in init_kernel
    shell_stream = ZMQStream(self.shell_socket)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 106, in __init__
    self.io_loop = io_loop or IOLoop.current()
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 127, in current
    loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 263, in current
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 671, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ScriptRunner.scriptThread'.
2022-02-29 15:20:13.094 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 991, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 113, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 665, in initialize
    self.init_sockets()
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 303, in init_sockets
    assert self.context is None, "init_sockets cannot be called twice!"
AssertionError: init_sockets cannot be called twice!
```

I have checked the app running "streamlit hello" and it works well. So, I do not know what is really going on.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: check streamlit is there by using conda or pip list

Comment: Yes, it is. streamlit hello open the demo, therefore it is. I double checked anyway and yes, I can confirm it is there

Comment: So you first tried to run streamlit app ie `ipykernel_launcher.py` (is that your streamlit app?firstly ) by using `streamlit run ipykernel_launcher.py` command in anacoda terminal(which i assume) which throws error `Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
  command:

    streamlit run C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py [ARGUMENTS]` then you tried this recommendation and that lead to the error given above right?

Comment: and your streamlit app called ipykernel_launcher.py works properly while run it local terminal and it displays `streamlit hello` in the browser right?

Comment: I run the script for the streamlit application in "jupyter", then I got the Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following command: streamlit run C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py [ARGUMENTS]. (This was the output from "jupyter") Then, I opened the anaconda terminal and run the recommend: "streamlit run "C:\Users\.............py" which gave me the error above.

Comment: No, the ipykernel_launcher.py opens the browser like trying to open the app but only an error appears. The demo streamlit hello is something that I tried separately to double check that the problem is not the installation. The demo works well but does not have anything to do with my work or with ipykernel_launcher.py.

Comment: im bit confused @Mike may i show you how i run streamlit app in the answer section?

Comment: Yes please, go ahead

Comment: If you have written Streamlit code in a Jupyter Notebook, you cannot directly run it .

1. Convert Notebook to a Python script: You can convert your Jupyter Notebook into a standalone Python script using the Jupyter command-line tool. Open a terminal or command prompt and navigate to the directory where your notebook is located. Then use the following command:`jupyter nbconvert --to script your_notebook.ipynb`

Comment: then follow the steps given below (in my answer section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `C:\Users\amith\LipNet\app` inside app folder i have my streamlit application `streamlitapp.py`
2. open the Anacoda terminal and navigate to that directory by using

```
cd C:\Users\amith\LipNet\app
```

3. then I type

```
streamlit run streamlitapp.py
```

your streamlit app will be hosted locally on the default browser

[image]

[image]

i think you run script directly which will throw this indication:
[image]

if you run script directly in jupyter notebook it will throws error and warnings indication like this
[image]

Comment: Great!!! I understand now, and it works!! Finally the headache is gone. What I was trying to do is to run the recommended on jupyter as "streamlit run C:\User.....(and the rest of the warning)". But now I understand that I needed to create a python script and with Anaconda terminal navigate to that directory and run the streamlit with the name of the app. Thank you very much. Still learning everyday.