# connecting streamlit with jupyter lab notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, streamlit

i have my jupyter notebook in jupyter lab which hosted on a server. I want to connect to my notebook and extract result to my ui which is in streamlit
all my code is in small functions and then there is a main function which return the final results i want in ui

my ui will send some data to jupyter notebook and ut should process it

i am unable to think of any solution. please help if anyone has done something like this

Comment: I'm not following why you need a notebook? You can run Python code in conjunction with Streamlit to do the extra processing there. And if you did need to pass things, that is possible already. For example, if you did need to pass the result to elsewhere, you can have your Python code running along with Streamlit save the result as a file that your notebook can use.  I suggest looking at the resources discussed in response to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76476746/8508004) if you still think you need something besides Streamlit here.

Answer (score 0):

Streamlit is working with Python scripts. You need to export your code from notebook to Python script and then you can use Streamlit to build User Interface (UI).

Alternative can be serving notebook with UI, there are two frameworks that I'm aware of for serving notebooks with UI and code hidden:

- Voila framework - you can use ipywidgets to add interactive UI to your notebook (https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila)
- Mercury framework - it comes with set of interactive widgets, it is very simple to use, and offers easy deployment (https://github.com/mljar/mercury)